# Removing dependencies on MySql

Tags: mysql, dependencies

We have a project that at one time must have used a MySql server in the backend. We're all Microsoft SQL Server now, but our project still uses MySql.Data references and code like:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
```

How do I find and replace all these dependencies so I can drop the references to MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6?

These dependencies are wrecking havoc on deploying an upgraded application to a newer server.

Comment: remove(after a backup) the using of mysql and look for errors, which some luck, the are all at one place

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nbk is right. It was tedious but I just had to remove all usages of the MySql library and replace them with System.Data.SqlClient properties/methods.

I was a bit confused because there was a simultaneous unrelated problem with a nuget package another developer had added to the project that was 'veiling' the errors I was seeing with MySql. :-(

Bob